# Tubular jquery video not starting in Safari 7 (mac)

Tags: jquery, video, safari, youtube-api, tubular

I'm using the tubular plugin (http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/) to create a subtle html video background. This works in Chrome, but in Safari 7 on Mac, the video won't start.

I've narrowed it down to the z-index being the reason of why safari won't autostart the video. When I change the z-index of the tubularContainer (defaults to 1) to a value above my other content (e.g. 9999) the video starts just fine.

```
var tubularContainer = '<div id="tubular-container" style="overflow: hidden; position: fixed; z-index: 1; width: 100%; height: 100%"><div id="tubular-player" style="position: absolute"></div></div><div id="tubular-shield" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;"></div>';
```

Does anyone know how to circumvent this safari behaviour? It's as if the video won't start when there's content above it with z-index.

Answer (score 2):

I've been hacking apart jQuery Tubular for a project that requires full-screen YouTube videos that ended up going a lot farther than I initially thought.  I ran into this as well and couldn't simply swap out the plugin due to having already altered Tubular to provide callbacks and other features.

This is how I fixed safari:

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player('tubular-player', {
        width: options.width,
        height: Math.ceil(options.width / options.ratio),
        videoId: options.videoId,
        playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            wmode: 'transparent',
            rel: 0,
            autoplay: 1,
            html5: 1
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

(this is code altered directly in jquery.tubular.js)

The main thing to notice is the **html5: 1** which encourages the use of the HTML5 player.  I don't know why Safari was defaulting to using Flash but it *was* and that was the problem for me.  Apparently there's some "battery-saving" mode that affects plugins like Flash.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect for a quick fix. For some reason I found replacing the original Tubular JS with the above fixed it in Safari, but then broke it in Chrome. I just used a conditional on the browsers and made use of both, might be useful for others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser

Answer (score 0):

The plugin seems incompatible with Safari's Power Saving feature.
Safari won't even play the video on their own homepage..

I use [Jquery-MB-YTPlayer](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-ytplayer/) instead