# Detect Safari and redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I currently use this script to detect and redirect a page when safari is used

```
if(/safari/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    window.location.href = "elsewhere.html"
}
```

however it redirects in safari and chrome.

how do I make it redirect only in safari only?

Comment: Can you post a link to the site?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser

Comment: _“I currently use this script to detect and redirect a page when safari is used”_ – what for?

Comment: hi i currently cant post the link as this is private. but the problem im facing is that it redirects on both safari and chrome. how do i only detect and redirect in safari only

Comment: @CBroe i want to show my users a different page when they use safari as i have some content that does not work in safari

Comment: Maybe you should fix that content instead of trying to detect Safari?

Comment: hmm from what i see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser it only detects safari. but how do i redirect? @Skwal

Comment: ok managed to get it to work! thanks for your help!

Comment: @xeflip Then add an answer yourself to this question showing how you solved it, so future users will learn from you!

Comment: I hope the page you redirect to is the download page for Chrome or FireFox. Because Safari should not be considered a browser in the first place... I can even fix problems in IE8, but this piece of crap is another story...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My smart code is:

```
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if(/safari/.test(uagent) && !/chrome/.test(uagent))
{
    window.location.href = "elsewhere.html"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this simple code:**

```
if(/safari/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && !/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))
{
    window.location.href = "elsewhere.html"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this script into your header. It should detect and redirect safari only. Just change  window.location.href = "somewhere.html" to the url you want to redirect safari users.

```
<script>
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
 if (ua.indexOf('safari')!=-1){ 
   if(ua.indexOf('chrome')  > -1){

   }else{
    window.location.href = "somewhere.html" // saf
   }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(typeof navigator.vendor!='undefined' && navigator.vendor.toLowerCase().indexOf('apple')!=-1){
 // redirection
}
```