# Amatic SC font - Rendering 'ee'

Tags: html, css, fonts, character-encoding, google-webfonts

I'm having an issue with the [Amatic SC font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amatic+SC?selection.family=Amatic+SC), specifically when trying to render two 'e' characters next two each other.

As you can see on the google fonts page, it should look like this.

[image]

However, on my website I get this effect:

[image]

It may be hard to see, but the two 'e' characters have been joined together as one character. When highlighting the text, they act as one character.

In addition, if I print out a long string of characters like 'eeeeeeee' and increase the letter spacing, you can clearly see the problem.

[image]

I can't seem to find any information on this, so any help is greatly appreciated as it is quite annoying!

Comment: Great font but used to have some issues since 2011. Can you please provide a test URL (Fiddle, Codepen or a staging url) so we can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z8nfdzqh/1/ You can see here that it seems to be an issue with the lowercase e's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce this error, but [as per an older Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682271/safari-kerning-issue-when-using-f-and-i), this issue (which is a typographic ligature issue), was previously produced due to a Safari bug with some fonts.

Try adding to your stylesheet for the affected elements:

```
 -webkit-font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
```

You can check to see if the issue is still present with and without these properties in your browser:

[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lymelight/6wu6exbq/2/)

If the issue isn't present in either element, it might mean there's some other property on the element on your site that is causing this issue.

EDITED THE ANSWER SO I CAN MARK AS SOLUTION

I'm not entirely sure why this worked, but adding the following CSS to the relevant tags fixed this problem:

```
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
```

Comment: Yeah it is still visible to me https://jsfiddle.net/6wu6exbq/3/ . Do you not see the double e's here?

Comment: No, neither example has any shared ligatures for me, but it's good that they're visible for you in that example. Are they visible in both lines of text, the red and the green? Either way, it sounds like a browser-issue. Can you tell me which browser you're using?

Comment: Yeah both lines it is visible. I'm using Chrome 58.

Comment: I've added a few more varied properties [to the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lymelight/6wu6exbq/10/) - do you still see double-E's on every single one of those strings?

If so, I'm not sure what to suggest, beyond a browser update to Chrome 59? Out of curiosity, is your OSX language set to something other than English?

Comment: Ahh! I only see the effect on the first two strings - the next three all look as intended.

Comment: Ah, that's excellent, so it's likely `font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;` property that will turn this off for your site.

Comment: Yes thank you very much! I've edited your answer with this so I could mark it as an accepted solution but i'm not sure if the edits have been approved yet

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because my rep is too low, however, I tried to replicate your problem with no success:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8nfdzqh/)

**HTML**

```
<p>
 Where's the beef?<br />
 BEEEEEEEEEEEF
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC');
body {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Is it possible you have some sort of code running somewhere that combines the E's into one character? If you could show us in a codepen or fiddle, or provide steps to reproduce, that would be very helpful in getting your problem solved.

Comment: I added a line of CSS to your code to change the letter spacing and it seems as though it works with the lowercase e's. https://jsfiddle.net/z8nfdzqh/1/

Comment: Is it possible this is an issue with your browser? Have you tried other browsers and browser versions? I can't see it on my machines.

Comment: Can't seem to see it on mobile using Chrome and Safari. Only works on my Mac, with Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox?