# Different CSS on Safari

Tags: css

The CSS that I wrote for the header is not working well on safari but it is working on the other web browsers.

The problem that I am having is that on chrome, etc. the `margin-top` from my logo is on `-30px` but on Safari it needs to be `-15px`

I have already tried a few things but it is not taking me anywhere. This is a example of what I have tried:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    .header-center-items {
    margin-top: -30px;
    }

    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome,.header-center-items {
     margin-top: -15px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact solution, but more of a work around.
You could the following:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    .header-center-items {
      margin-top: -30px;
    }

    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome,.header-center-items {
      position: relative;
      top: 15px;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you for you're time, but it seems like safari is not reading the "override", because when i am inspecting i don't see it anywhere

Comment: @AkramTarioui Hmm, seems like you can't use that selector any more then. 

Then you just have to use some simple javascript to fix this. Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120893/how-to-set-media-query-for-safari-web-browser)

Comment: i really don't know where to put the javascript it is a wordpress site and i am just changing the CSS, do you know where i can add the script? i am new in the developer world, thank you for you're response.