# Polymer Project not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm developing a websites using Paper/Core Elements with HTML Import of [Polymer Project](http://polymer-project.org). As subjested in some post about Polymer and Polyfill, I have imported 'webcomponents.js' that matches to 'platform.js'. That solved my problem partially, only for Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. On Safari its not still working.

I'd like to avoid to change framework, because polymer seems to be the best.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what's not working.

Comment: Which version of Polymer do you use?

Comment: All of components using Polymer v0.5, just see you official Polymer Homepage on Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I dont think Safari is supported. Here:

https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html

Safari doesn't support HTML imports at the time.

Comment: No, you're not wrong, I had also read that table, but I knew that if this was not checked, the compatibility was partial and not totally incompatible. 

Now, to solve this, i'm using an other web framework like ios ui, only for safari.

If someone else wants to adopt the same idea, this can be useful: HOW 

TO CHECK SAFARI BROWSER http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser

FRAMEWORK 7 (iOS UI)
http://www.idangero.us/framework7/get-started/

Thanks to all,
Marco