# Detect Safari browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, detection

I found this code snippet, which checks if Safari browser is used:

```
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement);
```

but I don't really know what's going on here. Could someone explain me how it works? I know that `constructor` returns the function that created the RegExp object's prototype and `i` performs case-insensitive matching, but what exactly is `HTMLElement`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In safari, `window.HTMLElement` returns a function which is named `HTMLElementConstructor`.

So let do this:

```
/constructor/i.test(function HTMLElementConstructor() {}) // return true
```

But with other browsers (FF, Chrome), it returns `HTMLElement`

```
/constructor/i.test(function HTMLElement() {}) // return false
```

But thank you for this observation! I hope we can use it as well as the method mentionned here: [Detect Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser)

Comment: This is no longer true with iOS 11 (possibly earlier?)