# Right Margin in Safari Browser Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the link to the website
http://lotussystems.in/

When I open it in Chrome(mobile) it works perfect, but when I open it on safari(mobile) then there is a right margin or what it there and also an x-axis scroll is coming, while I Mention overflow-x is hidden. if I put overflow-x hidden then it's not working.

Can anyone plz help me out.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Looks like padding problems on your `vc_single_image-img attachment-full`class

Comment: you can see by inspect element, because of that site in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

When I emulate a phone browser on your webpage in Chrome, the problem I see is in this line of the markup:

```
<div class="call-icon">
    <h5 class="text-center" id="#callbox">
        Talk to us
    </h5>
</div>
```

...and this line:

```
<div class="popup-header">
   <span class="popup-title">CONTACT
      <div class="popup-image"></div>
   </span> 
</div>
```

...and this line:

```
<a href="#" class="ti_scroll bounceInRight  animated" style="display: block;">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
</a>
```

All of these elements spill over into the right margin, so you need to change their `right-margin` CSS styles so that they don't have a foot in the right margin. It renders fine in Chrome mobile, but not Safari mobile because the two browsers are rendering your margins slightly differently. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser) on how to detect Safari with Javascript in order to change styles for specific browsers.

**Side Note:**

In the future, linking your website to StackOverflow without also posting static code is not considered proper [Asking Etiquette](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can
>   link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/)
>   then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not
>   everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.