# regex in JavaScript to identify browser type is not returning expected value - test(navigator.userAgent)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to find a way to identify the browser through JavaScript to disable a component based on the browser for a feature requirement in Volvo US project that involves AR (Augmented Reality).
**Platform**: Web Application

**Approach Attempted**:

```
    var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var isChromeBrowser = navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome");
    var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.includes('Firefox');
```

**Problem Statement**:
In the above approach, Safari is detecting Firefox browser as Safari browser & Safari browser as Safari.

**Expected Output**:
Need a solution where the method clearly returns Safari* browser alone as safari. (not for the Firefox browser or any other browsers)

Looking forward to any inputs towards a solution.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser)

Comment: Could you instead test for the feature you require?

Comment: @KevinB it is not possible in this case/scenario. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: @KevinB but can you please explain a bit more, when you mean feature? I am not sure of it. Kindly help.