# How to load and run a javascript file conditionally

Tags: javascript

I have a usecase where i need to load and execute different js file in my html file depending upon the browser type.

If browser is safari i need to load  `<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascripts/applepay.js">` and if browser is any other i need to load two js files`<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascripts/googlepay.js"></script>` and `<script async src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js" onload="onGooglePayLoaded()"></script>` .

Could you please let me know how  can this be done?I tried a couple of solutions mentioned in other posts but it didnt work for me. Any code snippets will be very helpful.

Comment: To determine the browser, you'll want to rely on the user agent string value. I assume you already know how to load the javascript file, so I won't address that. Regarding the actual decisioning part, you'll want to load a main javascript file that will load, regardless of the user agent. In that file, you would then detect the user agent and load the corresponding javascript file.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is happening while the main HTML is loading. You can then use `document.write()` to insert the HTML for the appropriate script.

```
<script>
if (is_safari()) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascripts/applepay.js"></' + 'script>');
} else {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascripts/googlepay.js"><' + '/script>');
    document.write('<script async src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js" onload="onGooglePayLoaded()"><' + '/script>');
}
</script>
```

See [Detect Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944460/detect-safari-browser) for a number of ways to implement the `is_safari()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can create regexp to determine browser with `window.navigator.vendor` as below

```js
if (window.navigator.vendor.match(/[Aa]+pple/g).length) {
  document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='./javascripts/applepay.js'>")
} else {
  document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='./javascripts/googlepay.js'></script><script async src='https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js' onload='onGooglePayLoaded()'></script>")
}
```