# Is there a feature detection equivalent for ARIA attributes, like aria-owns?

Tags: wai-aria, browser-feature-detection

Best practice web development would use [browser feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) to determine if a feature is present and properly supported by a browser, instead of say [version detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522755/1101109). For example by using [CSS.supports()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports) in JavaScript.

Is there a way to feature detect [aria-owns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-owns)?

For additional context it looks like [aria-owns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-owns) has been improved recently in [WebKit Bug Id 151498](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151498) though it has at the time of writing yet to make it into a [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-technology-preview-release-notes/stp-release-167).

Comment: https://a11ysupport.io/tech/aria/aria-owns_attribute is probably your best bet, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - that did come up in my research though I can only see implementing it with version detection (once the versions become known), not any actual feature detection. Might just be the state of AX/a11y right now.